# Examples showing conversion of a WCF REST service to ASP.NET OWIN?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, rest

I've got a stand alone WCF service providing REST services. As time goes on, I'm feeling like MS is going to reduce support for WCF and REST services, and I've already had to code in a bunch of hacks to get somethings working like CORS. Additionally, implementing https is another hack since it requires using OS functionality. (i.e. you have to install the certificate using an external application, which doesnt' make the service very self contained)

In anycase, I'm considering either a move to ASP.NET REST API and OWIN, or Java/Spring. I wanted to first see what it would take to move to ASP.NET REST, since I figured that should take the smallest amount of work, but I haven't found any good examples.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty straightforward example on the asp.net site.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

- setup a self-contained project i.e console app or windows service
- initialise and setup you routes
- create your Controller / API stubs
- deploy

Regarding SSL, whether it's IIS or Apache you will have to configure it on the web server regardless.

Comment: I'm not looking for an ASP.Net example by itself. I was hoping for something that showed best practices for converting all of my DataContract and DataMember attributes to the new ASP.Net rest methods.

Comment: It's an impossible and subjective post bpeikes. Does you existing WCF serve just serve REST requests/responses? If so, WCF seems like a bizarre choice as it offers so much more than rest and is quite bloated in terms of configuration etc. Why don't you post some excerpts of your existing code base?

Comment: My WCF does just serve REST request, but I find that it's much less bloated. All I have to do is define [DataContract] for my objects, and [OperationContract] for my service interfaces, and I'm pretty much ready to go. With ASP.Net REST it seems like you have to do a huge amount by hand, and deal with Http specific semantics in your code.

My current WCF REST implementation 99% of the HTTP semantics in special handlers outside the code, or templated in interfaces.